# add query parameters to a HTTP Post request by OkHttp?

Tags: android, kotlin, post, parameters, request

I am new to coding in Android Studio and have been trying to make an application where i am using latest OkHTTP for making a post request to my server and i need to parse accountId and one key in body and for that i have used this code :- [image: this is my request to parse parameters in body]

now i wants to add name and username in query parameters. what i need to add in the code for this? Please help me....Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be inside the body? If you are struggling, why not use Retrofit, which works over okttp3?

Comment: Query parameters are for a GET request and are added to the url. But you can POST and GET together by just adding the parameters to the url. Well i used to do so.. dont know if okhttp does it.